# What is a " B & A" puzzle?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, lateral-thinking, rebus

I think this type of puzzle format is a bit different from some you already have seen.

I call them B & A puzzles. After you solve them you will likely know what that means.

There are six seperate rebus/wordplay types listed below. The answer to each one is *two words minimum*. (May include numbers)

**No Partial Answers. Please answer all six.**

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't figure out the rest yet, but: rot13(N cbffvoyr nantenz bs #2 vf NHAG ZVQTR.)

Comment: @Sciborg uvyr lbh znl or ba gur evtug genpx, gung vf abg gur nafjre. Zl fhttrfgvba vf gb fbyir gur fvzcyrfg bar svefg ( znl or ahzore fvk) juvpu jvyy tvir lbh na vqrn bs jung O naq N vf. Tbbq Yhpx

Comment: @Sciborg I guess it should be rot13(zntavghqr). Also I think #4 is the easiest: it's simply rot13(ebg13(pbybavrf)).

Comment: @Whatsup Ahh, nice catch! :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure I know what 1 and 6 are, and the common theme, but I'm struggling to relate it to the others, so with the ban on partials I'll ahve to leave it. B & A still makes no sense though.

Comment: @Mohirl Unir lbh jngpurq gur zbfg cbchyne tnzr fubj va HF?

Comment: @DrD I don't live there, so probably not

Comment: @Mohirl That one is shown all over the world with local versions in the local languages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ok, not a partial answer, but obviously I don't know if all are correct

> they are all B&A before and afters

Number one

> **monkey business card**  - monkey (macaque) business and business card

Number two

> Thanks to Stiv and the OP for spoon feeding this:
>  **reverse alphabetic order of magnitude** - reverse alphabetic order (the jumble) and order of magnitude (magnitude is anagrammed)
>
>  my wrong answer -- mixed up size - mixed up (anagram) and up size (magnitude is anagrammed)

Number three

> **cloud nine to five** -  cloud nine and nine to five (arrow)

Number four

> **rot 13 colonies**  - rot 13 (used to encrypt)  13 colonies, the original US

Number five

> **six feet under the sun** - six feet (shown) under and under the sun
>
>  False trails...
>  **six feet deep tan** - six feet (shown) deep and deep tan (on legs)
>  **black and white sandy beach** --black and white (pic) and white sandy beach
>  **out of line of the horizon** -- out of line (the one person who is different) and line of the horizon (where sky meets water)

Number six

> **red square root** - red (color) square  and square root symbol

Comment: Way to go @SteveV. Did not get 2 and 5. Try again.

Comment: For 2, how about rot13(bhg bs beqre bs zntavghqr)?

Comment: @Stiv i think that's much better!

Comment: @Stiv V jnf guvaxvat

Erirefr Nycunorgvpny Beqre bs Zntavghqr

Comment: @DrD Ha, you know I hadn't even spotted that was the case!

Comment: BTW @SteveV  "Phevbhf Trbetr" vf nyyrtrqyl n Znpndhr Zbaxrl!

Comment: I started out looking for "n "Phevbhf Trbetr" pbaarpgvba!"

Comment: @DrD added a couple more tries for no. 5.

Comment: @SteveV . What was the popular saying starting with fvk srrg which was also a very popular UOB fubj?

Comment: @DrD  hopefully my last edit :)

Comment: I was sure that no. 2 was rot13(hazvgvtngrq qvfnfgre nern) but it's missing some letters :(

Comment: I still don't understand the title? Why are they called "B&A"?

Comment: @Stef B&A stands for rot13("Orsber naq Nsgre", juvpu vf jung gurl pnyy guvf glcr bs chmmyr ba gur Nzrevpna dhvm fubj, "Wrbcneql")

Comment: @SteveV thanks!