# A Before and After puzzle (2)

Tags: wordplay, rebus

This is a "B & A" puzzle linked to

[What is a " B & A" puzzle?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102250/what-is-a-b-a-puzzle)

It describes a before and after word chain which has a word in common. For example:

**First Lady Gaga**: Before would be "First Lady" and after would be "Lady Gaga"

Here are **Three seperate** Rebus B&As (three images) and one non Rebus. So need 4 answers. Number 4 is not part of the 4th B&A. All answers are minimum 3 words long

**No Partial Answers please**

[image: FIRST]

[image]

[image]

**4   TSDIEECGBEGN**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Number 1

> Cattle Drive In

Number 2 (suggested by Stiv in comments)

> Second Banana Split
>  **Original Incorrect Answer:** Banana Split Screen

Number 3

> Olympic Record Labels

Number 4

> Scrambled Eggs Benedict

Comment: got all except the banana one. Great job though

Comment: #2 may involve [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/second%20banana), giving you rot13(FRPBAQ ONANAN FCYVG)...

Comment: @Stiv, thanks, that looks good (the phrase you suggested is not one I'm very familiar with)

Comment: that is what i was thinking

Comment: Never heard that phrase either, learn something new everyday on Puzzling SE

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the others, but number 2 could be

> Banana split pairs