# Another Before and After Puzzle

Tags: wordplay, rebus

Linked to [A Before and After puzzle (2)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102669/a-before-and-after-puzzle-2)

The answers will be at least three words which will be a combination of two seperate word phrases such as desribed in the links. Example

Diamond Ring   and  Ring Leader   give   Diamond ring leader

The following 5 seperate images are the B&A rebuses. **Please no partial answers.** Five images are not connected. There could be a trick on some words.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I think they are

Number 1

> Split Decision Overturned

Number 2

> Pink Eye Shadow

Number 3

> Mixed Nuts and Bolts

Number 4

> Sign of the Times Square

Number 5

> Red C Clamp (thanks to OP for the hint, Red Sea/C Clamp)

Previous idea for Number 5

> G Clamp Down

Comment: Just beat me! I think #5 is rot13(bcra p pynzc, ersreevat gb bcra P ghavat bs n thvgne)

Comment: @hexomino  Number 4 your answer is better than mine. Number 5 -- please re think. A play on word here.Guvax pbybe

Comment: @JeremyDover I like your interpretation although OP seems to be hinting at something else.

Comment: Play on C  so Erq Frn be P Pynzc