# A themed B&A Puzzle

Tags: visual, rebus

Inspired by [DrD](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34419/drd)'s original [What is a "B&A" Puzzle?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102250/what-is-a-b-a-puzzle)

This puzzle consists of 10 rebuses/visual clues that clue three-word phrases, where the first two words/numbers and the last two words/numbers each form a saying, title, or some other recognizable phrase. All ten rebuses conform to a theme, and the clues are ordered in a manner related to that theme. A correct answer will solve each clue (be careful with #10!) as well as provide the theme. I hope you enjoy!

1. [image: Clue 1]
2. [image: Clue 1]
3. [image: Clue 3]
4. [image: Clue 4]
5. [image: Clue 5]
6. [image: Clue 6]
7. [image: Clue 7]
8. [image: Clue 8]
9. [image: Clue 9]
10. [image: Clue 10]

Comment: Very nice. Are partial answers OK?

Comment: @DrD It's only been up a few hours, so I suggest holding off on a partial unless you have most of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are

> Beatles songs (in alphabetical order)

In order:

> 1. "Another Girl" Interrupted (Girl, Interrupted)

> 2. Breaking "Bad Boy" (Breaking Bad)

> 3. "Come Together" Forever (Together forever)

> 4. Cat "Lady Madonna" (Cat lady) - also possible is Foxy "Lady Madonna"

> 5. Chicken "Little Child" (Chicken Little)

> 6. Dr. "No Reply" (Dr. No)

> 7. "Norwegian Wood" Duck (Wood duck)

> 8. Trade "Paperback Writer" (Trade paperback)

> 9. Half"Penny Lane" (Halfpenny)

> 10. French "Revolution 9" (French Revolution)

Comment: Looks great! A couple of notes: I was going for rot13(sbkl ynql) in #4, but given the clue I can't argue with your answer. #7 doesn't need the extra letters, rot13(jbbq qhpx) is a thing. Your #8 is a little stretchy, since it doesn't use the full middle word...the second half is correct. The contents of the headline might give you an idea. And #10 only has two words...you need a third...the inset matters! But all in all, awesome job!!

Comment: Okay, @JeremyDover I think I definitely got them this time. :) Great puzzle!

Comment: Almost there! #10 is a toughie. As a hint, the fact that the stopwatch reads 11 seconds is significant.

Comment: rot13(eribyhgvba 1?)

Comment: I thought that, but that doesn't fully make sense to me either.

Comment: Hint: there is a way to determine which rot13(eribyhgvba) the picture is on.

Comment: @JeremyDover (Vs guvf vf n 33 1/3 ECZ erpbeq cynlre, gura vg'f ba gur 7gu eribyhgvba. Gur 2aq serapu eribyhgvba vf nyfb pnyyrq gur Whyl Eribyhgvba, vf gung gur nafjre? Whyl vf gur 7gu zbagu naq nyy.)

Comment: Singles (as the one pictured) used to run at a different speed than LP (long-play) albums. Dear lord, I am dating myself hard.

Comment: @JeremyDover Hah! I knew there were two different speeds but couldn't identify it by sight in a photo like that. I think I probably have it now.

Comment: Bingo! It's the fat spindle in the middle that gives it a way. LPs have a thin spindle.